# How can I use filter formula in google sheets to filter from a column of text

Tags: google-sheets

I have a table with a column of tags, which is comma-separated and could be single or multiple text, eg "single", "not single". I also have a separate table that contains tags that I want to filter.

I have tried a combination of filter, regex and join formulas, eg `=filter(data, regexmatch(some range, join some contents of filter strings)` but they don't work and I am lost.

Help. Thanks and much appreciated.

Example (simplified for illustration):

**TAGS** - could just be a column in a sheet

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | random, words of, no meaning |
| 2 | random |
| 3 | words of |
| 4 | no meaning |

**FILTER WORDS** - in a separate sheet but could grow

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | random |
| 2 | words of |

**IDEAL RESULT** - in a separate sheet using filter formula

|  | A |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | random, words of, no meaning |
| 2 | random |
| 3 | words of |

Comment: Sorry for the textual way. Could be confusing. If there's a better way to represent tables here, I, a noobie, need help.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data, and showing your _hand-entered_ expected results there.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the tags are in column `A2:A`, and the filter words are in `F2:F`, try using `regexmatch()` with `textjoin()` like this:

`=filter( A2:A, regexmatch(A2:A, textjoin("|", true, F2:F)) )`